# SSL and port forwarding in Jelastic: Deploying Strapi

Tags: docker, strapi, jelastic

I'm just discovering Jelastic, and I have difficulties to run Strapi.

So far, I just have one node, that is a Docker Strapi image, with SLB (no specific load balancer).

This node is accessed with SLB, and both public IPv4 and IPv6 are available.

I redirect a subdomain to these public IPs

I can launch Strapi in the container. However, it does not work well because of two issues:

1. **SSL is not available**. I can't install Let's Encrypt Free SSL: "the add-on cannot be installed on this node"...
2. **Port is not redirected**, and I have to explicitly indicate the port in the browser url to access the app homepage.

With these two issues, Strapi cannot work properly.

DOCKER_EXPOSED_PORT 1337 and MASTER_IP are set up for the Docker container.

How can I solve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

> SSL is not available. I can't install Let's Encrypt Free SSL: "the
> add-on cannot be installed on this node"...

The [Jelastic Let's Encrypt add-on](https://jelastic.com/blog/free-ssl-certificates-with-lets-encrypt/) can easily install on top of any container with the Custom SSL support enabled, namely the following servers (the list is constantly extended):

Load Balancers - NGINX, Apache LB, HAProxy, Varnish

Java application servers - Tomcat, TomEE, GlassFish, Payara, Jetty

PHP application servers - Apache PHP, NGINX PHP

Ruby application servers - Apache Ruby, NGINX Ruby

If you require Let's Encrypt SSL for any other stack, just add a load balancer in front of your application servers and install the add-on. SSL termination at load balancing level is used by default in clustered topologies. Docker containers are not on the list of supported nodes.

> Port is not redirected, and I have to explicitly indicate the port in
> the browser url to access the app homepage.

When using an external IP address, for correct forwarding you can can add two redirection rules to iptables and redirect all requests from port 80 or 443 to 1337, for example:

```
*nat
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1337

*filter
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

If you will not use an external IP address, you can apply the solution indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367870/port-forwarding-in-jelastic-with-docker) or get additional information indicated at this [link](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-ports/):